# Can two objects have multiple types of relationships?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, uml

Say I have a many to many relationship in the database like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (ID int, name varchar(100), dateofbirth datetime, Gender char(1), primary key (ID))
CREATE TABLE Sport (ID int, description varchar(30), primary key (ID))
CREATE TABLE PersonCanPlaySport (Person ID int references Person(ID), SportID int references Sport(ID), PRIMARY KEY (SportID, PersonID))
```

The tables show what sports a person can participate in.  Now see the class below:

```
public class Person
{
   public List<Sport> Sports;
   public int FitnessLevel;
   public datetime DateOfBirth;
   public string Gender; //M or F

   public Person()
   {
     Sports = new List<Sport>();
   }

   //allSports contains all the sports from the database i.e. allSports contains about 100 sports.  AddSports determines what sports (out of the 100) that the user can participate in based on: Gender, age, Fitness Level etc
   public void AddSports(List<Sports> allSports)
   {
      Sports.Clear();
      ((List<Sport>)Sports).AddRange(allSports
      .Where(sport => sport.CanPlay(this)));
   }

}
```

There appears to be an Association relationship and a Composition relationship between Person and Sports.  Here is why:

1) Person creates an instance of a list of sports in the constructor so controls the lifecycle of Sports
2) Person uses a List of sports in AddSports, which I believe makes it Association

Is this a code smell? What kind of relationship exists between the two objects? How would this be represented on an Object Diagram?

**Update**

Following on from the helpful answer and comments from @Neil; I believe he is suggesting doing this:

```
//Application Service Layer
List<Sport> sports = Repository.GetAllOffers();
foreach sport As Sport in sports
{
   person.AddSports(sport);
}

//Domain class
public class Person
{
   public List<Sport> Sports;
   public int FitnessLevel;
   public datetime DateOfBirth;
   public string Gender; //M or F

   public Person()
   {
     Sports = new List<Sport>();
   }

   public void AddSport(Sport sport)
   {
      if(sport.CanPlay(this))
      {
         Sports.Add(sport);
      }
   }

}
```

I am not sure if I like the idea that the Application Service layer has to loop through the Sports.

Comment: Having a collection does *not necessarily* mean that `Person` controls the lifecycle of the `Sport` elements in that collection.

(It does, however, control/own the lifecycle of the collection object itself — but that is a very low level relationship: merely an artifact of (collections in) objects.)

Comment: @Erik Eidt, the collection is populated in the constructor meaning the collection is created and destroyed by person making it a composition relationship.  Isn't that right?

Comment: no, for these purposes, you have to distinguish between the collection object itself, and the elements in the collection. On the one hand, if the collection object is only referenced by the Person object, destroying (loosing) the Person object will loose the collection object.  On the other hand, loosing the collection will not necessarily loose the elements in the collection, especially if they are managed elsewhere, such as having the persistence holding those relationships and entities, so loosing in-memory object doesn't necessarily affect the persistence.

Comment: Firstly: not a good design. What if I called `AddSports` with sports that the person could not play or take part in? But about your question of composition and association: even if you call this composition, the list of sports I passed in could have existed before `Person` object came into existence and may even exist after `Person` is garbage collected. Now you may say "ok so then its association"--maybe but maybe not. Depends on what you do with it.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, can you post some code in an answer? Are you saying that AddSports should not accept a collection?

Answer (score 3):

The database relationship between `Person` and `Sport` as I understand it is many-to-many, with a intermediate table `PersonCanPlaySport` that connects the two.  This means a `Person` can be associated with many `Sports` and a `Sport` can be associated with many `Persons`.

Now that we understand the database relationship, the relationship used in the code should be no different.  Potentially a `Person` instance would have a list of `Sport` and a `Sport` instance would have a list of `Person`.

I think therefore it would be incorrect to put the logic of whether or not a `Person` should have a specific `Sport` directly inside `Person`, or vice versa.  Consider the use of a `PersonSportDao` object which given a `Person`, can return all `Sports` and given a `Sport` can return all `Persons`.  The caller to `AddSports` would make the call to `PersonSportDao`, or better still, `Person` instance itself loads its `Sports` when asked for it, calling `PersonSportDao` with `this`.

If you wish to check details regarding age or gender, you could create another class `PersonSportManager`.  In other words, `Person` isn't owner of `Sport` and so it should see none of the logic just as `Sport` isn't owner of `Person` and so *it* shouldn't see any of the logic of `Person`.

Had `Person` to `Sport` been a one-to-many relationship, I would have argued otherwise, but I think the code should reflect the symmetry of the relationship on the database.

Edit:  Answering your question:

> Is this a code smell? What kind of relationship exists between the two
>   objects? How would this be represented on an Object Diagram?

A composition relationship would imply that `Sports` make up `Person` which is like a one-to-many relationship between `Person` and `Sport`.  In your case that isn't true, being many-to-many.

The relationship is too complicated to simply draw a line between the two making it necessary to create a middle class, and then associating `Person` and `Sport` both to that middle class (such as `PersonSportManager`).

Hope that answers your question!

Comment: Adding an intermediary class is one way of resolving the impedance mismatch.  However, instead I have decided to: 1) Add a list of Sports to Person and 2) Not add a List of persons in Sport.  This makes the object relationship 0:M.  I have edited the question by adding code to the AddSports method.  Could you tell me what you think now?

Comment: For the reference to an intermediary class +1.  It is one way of approaching it.

Comment: @w0051977 Your way would work too, but you're still tightly coupling `Person` and `Sport` this way.  If you tell me `Sport` doesn't have a list of `Persons`, then you could eliminate the necessity for `Sport` to know about `Person` entirely, but it means your method `CanPlay` needs to be added to `Person` with a `Sport` instance passed to it.  So long as `Sport` doesn't need to know about `Person`, you'll have no conflict.  Otherwise, I would recommend my approach.

Comment: Thank you.  So what you are saying is - use my approach is Sport does not need to know about person and use your approach if it does?

Comment: @w0051977 Yes, essentially.  If they need to know about each other, a third class should be added to mediate.  Otherwise, your approach is fine.

Comment: I notice that you have not answered one of the questions in my last paragraph. Is there a Composition relationship and an Association relationship between the two classes? Is this a code smell?  I ask because Person.AddSports has a list of Sports passed to it populated externally to the class: Person.  Thanks.

Comment: @w0051977 Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks.  However, everywhere I read tells me not to create a junction class unless it is strictly necessary.  There is no such thing as a PersonSport in the Ubiqituous language after all - it is a database concept.  The code in my OP works very well, however I am consfused whether the relationship between person and sport (many to none) is an Association or composition - it appears to be both.

Comment: @w0051977 Your `PersonSport` database object is `PersonCanPlaySport` that matches the two tables in many-to-many relationship.  In your code, if you don't need to take advantage of the many-to-one `Person` to `Sport` relationship, you can effectively ignore it.  However I would still avoid calling it a *composition* since it isn't a composition relationship on the database.  That said, if you think your code works very well, you're free to do as you choose, ignoring my advice.

Comment: Thank you.  I think what you are saying is that this is an Association relationship rather than a Composition relationship.  Have I understood that correctly? I would agree with that.

Comment: @w0051977 Yes, that sounds about right.

Comment: *A composition relationship would imply that Sports make up Person* is not quite correct. It is not equivalent to parts make a whole. It's more about who owns whom. For example consider a person to cars--cars do not make a person and neither is a person made of cars but nonetheless composition can exist.

Comment: Can I ask one more think before I accept? Is it bad practice to pass a list do a domain method i.e. in my case I am passing a list of Sports to Person.AddSport? I do this without a second thought.  However, I have reviewed a few code bases on GitHub e.g. NHibernate and I cannot find a single example where this is done.  Every single example I find passed an object to a method rather than a list of objects.

Comment: @w0051977 Because a method accepting one `Sport` instance is adaptable whereas accepting a `List` of `Sport` may involve transforming into a `List` if only to call the method.  If anything you have an `AddSport` method *and* a `SetSports`.  Or better still, if no logic is to be performed, just make `Sports` a property of `Person` (not that you couldn't have logic in the setter, but it isn't best practice).  It's not necessarily worse, but it's generally more accepted to have an `AddSport` and maybe a `AddSports` but not vice versa.

Comment: @Neil, thanks again - I am nearly there.  I have shown what AddSports does in the question.  I could change it to AddSport, but then the service layer would have to loop through all the Sports and pass each sport to Person.AddSports().  I believe the code in my question is "better".  However, as I say - I cannot find a single example where a list is passed to a domain layer method rather than an object.

Comment: @w0051977 If you can add one sport, you can add many sports without providing a method that does this for you.  Also the existence of an AddSports method (as opposed to an AddSport method) makes me think handling a list of sports is somehow different than handling a sport one at a time.  That isn't your case I presume, so it would be misleading to someone reading your code.  However again, you're free to do as you choose.

Comment: I have added a comment in my OP above AddSports and I have added some properties to: Person.  This may help explain my misunderstanding.  I don't know from your last comment whether you are saying have a method called: AddSport or AddSports.  I realise this is subjective, however it would be good to get an opinion based on the information I have provided.  Thanks again.

Comment: `AddSport` is preferable.  If you feel you need `AddSports` method, then have both, with `AddSports` repeatedly calling `AddSport`.  Or again, if `Sports` is a property, someone could simply do `person.Sports.Add(sport)`, eliminating the need to have an `AddSport` method at all.

Comment: I have added an update to my OP.  Could you review it before I mark your answer?